# Blogger - Unable to set custom domain name - getting Error 12 and 404 page

Tags: blogs, web-hosting, blogger, google-search-console, blogspot

I am unable to setup a custom domain name for my blogger site, I followed all the instructions mentioned on the below link but nothing has helped me so far (Note: Its been 3 days now).
Referred Link:
https://support.google.com/blogger/troubleshooter/1233381?rd=1#ts=1734115

Other details:

My blogger site: http://sandbox-addedbits.blogspot.in/

My Domain with www: http://www.addedbits.com/ [Note: Currently showing 404 - page not found]

Domain without www: http://addedbits.com/ [Note: Currently showing welcome page]

Also, find the screenshot of

1. Blogger's Third-party domain settings:
   [image: Blogger's Third-party domain settings]
2. Godaddy A(Host) Records:
   [image: Godaddy A record]
3. Godaddy CNAME Records:
   [image: Godaddy CNAME Records]

My Domain name verification has also failed using all the methods mentioned by Blogger.

Let me know if anyone can help me to setup custom domain name for blogger site.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is that a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the Issue yesterday. While investigating I noticed the my domain name was assigned 4 name servers. The two nameservers shown on settings tab were different from the two nameservers shown on DNS Zone file tab due to which Google blogger was unable to verify domain ownership [Note: I have attached the screenshot of the issue for users reference]. After replacing the two nameservers on "settings" tab with the two nameservers on "DNS Zone File" tab the issue got fixed.

**Godaddy Setting Tab Section:**
[image: Godaddy Setting Tab Section]

**Godaddy DNS Zone File Section:**
[image: Godaddy DNS Zone File Section]

Hope this information might help others!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I was facing but it was four years back and in that time i did not have any solution for the problem, so I got help from forums as well as support team of the domain registrar, even I got help from the article.

Which is having all step by step guide for setting up domain name for blog-
http://www.bloggerhowtoseotips.com/2013/07/How-to-Setting-Up-a-Custom-Domain-on-Blogger.html

Comment: Please add the relevant content from your link to the answer

Comment: @ujjwal, Thank you